# For $n$-gons $A$ and $B$, is it possible for $A$ to have shorter (or equal) corresponding edges but longer corresponding diagonals than $B$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n$-gons with sides $i$, $i=1,...,n$, and diagonals $ij$, denoting the diagonal between $i$ and $j$. 
>   Is it possible that the length of each side in $A$ is smaller than or equal to the length of corresponding side in $B$, and the length of each diagonal in $A$ is bigger than the length of corresponding diagonal in $B$?

I think using the law of cosines for sides and diagonals may work. 
But, is there easier solution?

Comment: No. This can only occur if A is convex and B is concave

Answer (score 0):

If both polygons are convex that is not possible. If 
$$
A_iA_{i+1}\le B_iB_{i+1},\quad
A_{i+1}A_{i+2}\le B_{i+1}B_{i+2},\quad
A_{i}A_{i+2}> B_{i}B_{i+2},
$$
if follows from elementary geometry that $\angle A_iA_{i+1}A_{i+2}>\angle B_iB_{i+1}B_{i+2}$, but this cannot hold for all $i$, as the sum of all angles is $(n-2)\pi$ for both polygons.

Comment: thanks. What if one of polygons is concave?

Comment: If one of the polygons is convex then there are examples showing that in some cases your inequality holds. To say something more one should carry out a tedious case-by-case analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If we allow non-convex, non-simple polygons, then you can compare a regular pentagon with a regular five-pointed star. If the star is inscribed in the pentagon then each figure's sides are the diagonals of the other figure.